# Different Response Headers for 404 Errors in Cascade API (Dart and Shelf)

Tags: flutter, dart, backend, dart-shelf, shelf-router

I had asked a question about this before, but I realized it got too long and complex, so I created a very simple case. In the code below I created two separate APIs, ApiA and ApiB, each with only one endpoint returning a 404.

Does anyone know why I only receive the "Response.notFound('body test', headers: {'head-test': 'test'})" in the last API added to the Cascade in the Main? In this example, ApiA is returning a "Response.notFound('Route not found')" without additional headers.

```
import 'package:shelf/shelf.dart';
import 'package:shelf_router/shelf_router.dart';
import 'package:shelf/shelf_io.dart' as shelf_io;

void main() async {
  var apiAHandler = ApiA();
  var apiBHandler = ApiB();
  var cascadeHandler = Cascade().add(apiAHandler.router).add(apiBHandler.router).handler;
  await shelf_io.serve(cascadeHandler, 'localhost', 8080);
  print('Server Online');
}

class ApiA {
  Router get router {
    Router router = Router();
    router.get('/apia', (Request req) async {
      return Response.notFound('body test', headers: {'head-test': 'test'});
    });
    return router;
  }
}

class ApiB {
  Router get router {
    Router router = Router();
    router.get('/apib', (Request req) async {
      return Response.notFound('body test', headers: {'head-test': 'test'});
    });
    return router;
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are confusing `Cascade` when you deliberately return a `notFound`. If you return `ok` you get the expected result. Is there a specific reason why you want to handle some endpoints in each api by saying that you "didn't handle them" (404) - rather than not handling them at all and letting things flow naturally through the cascade?

Comment: @RichardHeap I appreciate your insights about Cascade behavior and how it interacts with multiple "notFound" responses. However, I wanted to clarify that the provided code was intentionally simplified to isolate the specific issue I'm encountering.

In my actual code, which is more complex, the router.get('/person') endpoint has additional logic and handles different scenarios beyond returning a simple "notFound" response for missing persons. The specific error is occurring within the if (person != null) block, where I'm trying to retrieve and respond with the retrieved person's data.

Comment: Can you merge the 2 (or more) routers and not use cascade? Try returning 410 instead of 404 when you need to indicate "no user" - and then interpret that in the client.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It helped me find a solution.

I created ApiA and ApiB in separate files with a method to get router.

I created a third file called app_router.

    class AppRouter {
      Router get mergedRouter {
        final router = Router();
        router.mount('/', ApiA().router); // Corrected path
        router.mount('/', ApiB().router); // Corrected path
        return router;
      }
    }

I put this return on my server and it worked beautifully.